# Clicking on a link without Id or class

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have a code that does a research for the user in a website and then get the information from that research.
In the process of acessing the information, I need to click o a link inside the website. This link can change everytime the user makes a different research, so I can't use it's href to acess it. I have no clue about what to do.

Here's my code until now: it goes until the webpage where the link is.
Steps of the code:

1. user insert his research. example: "icms base de calculo pis cofins"
2. open ie in: http://www.stj.jus.br/SCON/
3. insert the research
4. click on: "sumulas", "decisões monocromaticas" and "informativos de jurisprudencia". That way I acess only the "acordãos".
5. click on "pesquisar"
6. I need to click on the link in front of "Acórdãos"

Here's the code:

```
Sub teses2()

    Dim pesquisa As String
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim elemns As Object
    Dim elem As Object
    Dim elemns2 As Object
    Dim elem2 As Object
    Dim elem3 As Object
    Dim obj As Object 

    pesquisa = InputBox("Digite os termos que quer pesquisar: ", "", "")
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://www.stj.jus.br/SCON/"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 20))
    ie.document.getElementById("pesquisaLivre").innerText = pesquisa

    Set elemns2 = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each elem2 In elemns2
        If elem2.Value = "SUMU" Then
            elem2.Click
        End If
        If elem2.Value = "DTXT" Then
            elem2.Click
        End If
        If elem2.Value = "INFJ" Then
            elem2.Click
        End If
    Next

    Set elemns = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each elem In elemns
        If elem.Value = "Pesquisar" Then
            elem.Click
        End If    
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You could simply pull the href from the control every time rather than having a static address. Alternatively, check the `InnerText` for the anchor tag (if it is an anchor tag) or the `Value` attribute if it is an `Input` tag.

Comment: It doesn't have an InnerText or  Value.

Comment: Is the button assigned by JavaScript?

Comment: Can you navigate IE to the href text? Would that open what you need?

Comment: I actually don't know Paul. And Ryan, I also don't know, can you acess the page and see ? It would help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

I have revisited this and made it tighter.

```
Option Explicit

Sub teses2()

    Dim pesquisa As String
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer


    '*SUSPENDED * pesquisa = InputBox("Digite os termos que quer pesquisar: ", "", "")
    pesquisa = "icms base de calculo pis cofins"

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://www.stj.jus.br/SCON/"

    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    While ie.Document.ReadyState = "complete"
        DoEvents
    Wend
    'Stop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))
    ie.Document.getElementById("pesquisaLivre").innerText = pesquisa

    Dim oHtml As MSHTML.HTMLDocument '* gives intellisense
    Set oHtml = ie.Document

    Dim oSelectors As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    Set oSelectors = oHtml.querySelectorAll("div.blocoCampos input")

    Dim lSelectorResultList As Long
    lSelectorResultList = oSelectors.Length

    Dim lSelectorResultLoop As Long
    For lSelectorResultLoop = 0 To lSelectorResultList - 1

        Dim objInputCheckbox As Object
        Set objInputCheckbox = oSelectors.Item(lSelectorResultLoop)

        If Not objInputCheckbox Is Nothing Then
            Dim sLabel As String
            sLabel = objInputCheckbox.Value

            If VBA.InStr(1, "|SUMU|DTXT|INFJ|", "|" & sLabel & "|", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                objInputCheckbox.Click
            End If

        End If
    Next
    '* release references
    Set objInputCheckbox = Nothing
    Set oSelectors = Nothing
    Set oHtml = Nothing

    Dim elemns As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    'Set elemns = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    Set oHtml = ie.Document
    Set elemns = oHtml.querySelectorAll("div#botoesPesquisa input:nth-child(1)")
    Debug.Assert elemns.Length = 1

    Dim elem As Object
    Set elem = elemns.Item(0)

    'For Each elem In elemns
        If elem.Value = "Pesquisar" Then
            elem.Click
        End If
    'Next


    '* release references
    Set elem = Nothing
    Set elemns = Nothing


    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'While ie.Document.ReadyState = "complete"
    '    DoEvents
    'Wend

    '* POST NAVIGATION
    'Stop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10))


    Set oHtml = ie.Document
    Dim objResultList As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    Set objResultList = oHtml.querySelectorAll("div#itemlistaresultados span:nth-child(2) a")

    Dim lResultCount As Long
    lResultCount = objResultList.Length

    Debug.Print
    Dim lResultLoop As Long
    For lResultLoop = 0 To lResultCount - 1

        Dim anchorLoop As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
        Set anchorLoop = objResultList.Item(lResultLoop)

        Debug.Print anchorLoop.href

    Next

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing

    'Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: My code already does that. The thing I need is after that, in the link that apears

Comment: Some explanatory notes http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2018/01/vba-webscraping-jquery-selectors.html